# create-react-app proxy api requests behind a corp proxy

Tags: node.js, reactjs, npm, create-react-app, react-scripts

Here is my situation,

I am creating a react app behind a corp firewall. My api server is running remotely on a different location. How to setup my proxy in the package.json so that I can hit the api servers through the corp proxy?

My configuration so far I have experimented with is this:

```
"proxy" : { 
     "/api/" : {
          "target" : "http://****myapiserver.com",
          "changeOrigin" : true,
          "agent" : {
              "host" : "pathtoproxy.com",
              "port" : 80
           }
      }
 }
```

I have tried several other combinations also without any luck. Anything I'm missing or wrong?

Also, my npm is configured, so that it has http and https proxy setup.

Comment: is there any error you could post? Maby try to add `"secure": false` to your proxy settings.

Answer (score 0):

Okay, so I solved this by writing a custom proxy - so now I have 3 proxies.

1. React Proxy - Which will be hit when the browser makes a call for the api.
2. My custom proxy that is "pipe-ing" the request from react app's proxy to corp proxy.
3. CORP Proxy, that allows me to reach the api server I want to hit.

   ```
   // React App's package.json  - runs on port 3000
   "proxy" : "http://localhost:3001"

   // myproxy.js - runs on port 3001
   var express = require('express')
   var request = require('request')

   const app = express();
   var serverRequest = request.defaults({'proxy':'http://path2.corp.proxy.com:port'})

   app.all('/', (req, res) => {
             let url = "http://myserver.com/api" + req.url
             req.pipe(serverRequest(url)).pipe(resp)
          );

   app.listen(3001);
   ```

Once I have this, I start my custom proxy as `node proxy.js`
Then I start my react app and everything works well, I can hit the api server.